# Determine for which values $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ the integral $\int_0^1 x^λ \ln x \, dx$ converges

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to find
$$\int_0^1 x^{\lambda}\ln x\,dx$$

So I've tried to find the indefinite integral 
$$\int x^{\lambda}\ln x\,dx$$ 
but then got confused as to how to prove what values it converges for.

Comment: Please use MathJax

Comment: Clearly when $\lambda\geqslant 0$, you can use the method (integral by parts) to get a certain finite value. Check that!

Comment: There is a variable named $\lambda$ in the expression, this does not make it lambda calculus!

Comment: For $\lambda \ne -1$ prove convergence or divergence by comparing to $\int x^\mu dx$ where $\mu$ is between $\lambda$ and $-1$.  Case $\lambda=1$ requires more computation than that.

Answer (score 1):

For $\lambda>-1$, the integral is$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}\int_0^1x^\lambda dx=\frac{d}{d\lambda}\frac{1}{\lambda+1}=-\frac{1}{(\lambda+1)^2}.$$

Comment: Could you share how you reached this integral? I'm quite confused, especially with the initial  ∂λ

Comment: @studentlovescalc See edit.

Comment: Uh I feel like I'm still missing something. What is ∂?

Comment: @studentlovescalc Maybe you haven't studied partial derivatives yet. I've made another edit to use the more familiar total derivative.

Comment: haha thank you that clears it up!